# How can I uninstall turtle graphics from Mac OS python interpreter?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Any time I try to run turtle graphics through the python interpreter on the Mac terminal, the turtle graphics screen is just black and jitters. This is the code I am using which I am pretty sure has no errors. I would like to know how I can uninstall the turtle graphics from my computer.

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("blue")

bob = turtle.Turtle()

sideLength = 300

bob.goto(-sideLength/2,-sideLength/2)

for i in range(4):
    bob.forward(sideLength)
    bob.left(90)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: turtle is part of the Python standard library. You can't uninstall it without uninstalling Python or corrupting your distribution.